# Import HTML/JS post to WordPress?

Tags: import

I have a working HTML/JS page that uses Google Maps:

http://test.barrycarter.info/sunstuff.html

How do I import this into wordpress.barrycarter.info?

Simply cutting/pasting or doing "`<?php include()?>`" doesn't work, 
since WP processes the result before displaying it, breaking the page:

http://wordpress.barrycarter.info/index.php/test-sunstuff-include-fail/

(use "view source" to see the hideously mangled JS).

I can't even use the "Google Maps v3 Shortcode" plugin, since the map 
overlays are generated client-side, not via KML.

Answer (score 2):

You could put this in as a theme page template. This would let you continue modifying your custom code.

Whatever you do, **avoid plugins that let you put raw php in your posts**. It's a huge security vulnerability, and it would let people do things such as submit draft posts containing shell scripts to turn your site into a zombie drone for an attacker.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [import plugin](http://sillybean.net/code/wordpress/html-import/) to get the rendered results and import these into WordPress.